# How to set http timeouts using axum (based on hyper)?

Tags: rust, hyper, rust-axum

I'm coming from Golang where I can simply use `http.Server` struct for timeout options like:

```golang
func start() {
  httpServer := &http.Server{
    ReadTimeout:  "30s",
    WriteTimeout: "1h",
    //...
  }

  err = httpServer.ListenAndServe()
}
```

I'm using [`axum`](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum) `{ version = "0.5.16", features = ["json"] }` right now and I would like to set these timeouts **but I cannot find out how**.

Can you help me?

I know `axum` is using [`hyper`](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper), can you help me understand how to do this?

I'm using the below code:

```rust
axum::Server::bind(&addr)
  .serve(app.into_make_service())
  .with_graceful_shutdown(shutdown_signal())
  .await
  .unwrap();
```

Comment: How is your `app` built? The following example (probably among others) demonstrates how to use Tower's `ServiceBuilder` in order to add timeout support to your app: https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/main/examples/key-value-store/src/main.rs#L63.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you make use of the `TimeoutLayer` in `tower_http`. You can configure it into your axum server like this:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let service = ServiceBuilder::new()
     .layer(HandleErrorLayer::new(handle_timeout_error))
     .layer(TimeoutLayer::new(Duration::from_secs(30)));

    let app = Router::new()
        .route(
            "/todos",
            get(controller::list_todos).post(controller::create_todo),
        )
        .layer(service);

    axum::Server::bind(&"127.0.0.1:3000".parse().unwrap())
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .expect("Failed to start server");
}


pub async fn handle_timeout_error(err: BoxError) -> AppError {
    if err.is::<timeout::error::Elapsed>() {
        AppError::RequestTimeout
    } else {
        AppError::Unexpected(err)
    }
}
```

You will need to customise this code, it is only an example and won't compile on its own.

The `TimeoutLayer` is part of `tower_http`, see here: https://docs.rs/tower-http/latest/tower_http/index.html

You might need to add something like

```ini
tower = { version = "0.4", features = ["timeout"] }
```

to your `Cargo.toml`.

---

If you're wondering what `AppError` is and why it can be returned from a handler, it's because I implemented `IntoResponse` for it (you don't strictly need this, you can just lazily return something like
`(StatusCode::REQUEST_TIMEOUT, "Timeout")`), I just included it because I thought it might be helpful):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum AppError {
    NotFound,
    ValidationFailed(ValidationErrors),
...
    RequestTimeout,
...
}

impl Display for AppError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match &self {
            AppError::ValidationFailed(_) => write!(f, "ValidationFailed"),
...
            _ => Debug::fmt(self, f),
        }
    }
}

impl IntoResponse for AppError {
    fn into_response(self) -> Response {
        let code = self.to_string();
        let (status, err): (StatusCode, AppErrorJson) = match self {
...
            AppError::NotFound => (
                StatusCode::NOT_FOUND,
                AppErrorJson::new(&code, "The requested resource could not be found", None),
            ),
            AppError::ValidationFailed(e) => (
                StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST,
                AppErrorJson::new(
                    &code,
                    "Unable to validate request",
                    Some(AppErrorDetail::Validation(e)),
                ),
            ),
            AppError::RequestTimeout => (
                StatusCode::REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
                AppErrorJson::new(&code, "Request timeout reached", None),
            ),
...
        };
        (status, Json(err)).into_response()
    }
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct AppErrorJson<'a> {
    code: &'a str,
    message: Cow<'a, str>,
    detail: Option<AppErrorDetail>,
}

impl<'a> AppErrorJson<'a> {
    fn new<S>(code: &'a str, message: S, detail: Option<AppErrorDetail>) -> Self
    where
        S: Into<Cow<'a, str>>,
    {
        AppErrorJson {
            code,
            message: message.into(),
            detail,
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you're wondering why `AppErrorJson.message` is a `Into<Cow<'a, str>>` and not just `String` or so, read this: https://jwilm.io/blog/from-str-to-cow/ being a Rust newbie myself, it helped me a lot to understand how to work with Rusts different string types effectively.